# Is it possible to use .NET Aspire across multiple .NET solutions?

Tags: .net, .net-8.0, dotnet-aspire, cloud-native

I have three dotnet **solutions** (and not projects) and each of them is made of a bunch of dotnet projects. I want to encapsulate them in a single Dotnet Aspire solution.

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. (Tested)

AppHost is project centric, not solution centric. I integrated project from completely different repo (and thus solution).

Aspire AppHost is ProjectReference based meaning it should work after you add ProjectReferences to Aspire AppHost csproj.

Then you should find generated code for your projects in `obj\$(CONFIGURATION)\$(TARGETFRAMEWORK)\Aspire`